# How to get two different url in background task

Tags: android

Below is my code which have one url in backgroundtask and get string on postexecute in my senario I have two http connection what do I do? url1 and url2 how both work onbackground parrallel?

```
public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {
            String query = URLEncoder.encode("American%20Cheese%20Burger", "utf-8");
            String url = "http://198.57.208.46/xyz";
            Log.i("url",""+url);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); 
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return _response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

but now I have one more http connection and get on postexecute parallel??
             like   protected void onPostExecute(String result,String result2)

```
            String url2 = "http://198.57.208.46/abc";
            Log.i("url",""+url);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); 
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

Comment: call new AsyncTask with url2 in onPostExecute method

Comment: u mean in each asyntask only  1 url http call??

Comment: why dont you pass String argument to doInBackground instead of Void ?

Comment: yes. but if you will, you can call both url requests in one doInBackground method.

Comment: but background retuen single string? and how i will get both url onpostexecute?

Comment: plz edit my code what u say inmy xode backgrond return single string

   return _response;

Comment: how i return two http request n background?? and get on postexecute??

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor and pass parameter to the method through constructor like

```
public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
   String url;
   public TheTask(String url) {
        this.url = url;
   }
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    try {
        String query = URLEncoder.encode("American%20Cheese%20Burger", "utf-8");
    //    String url = "http://198.57.208.46/xyz"; // now remove it, as url is declared at class level
        Log.i("url",""+url);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); 
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
         _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return _response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tv.setText(result);
}
```

}
}

now You can call this async task like

```
new TheTask("your_url").execute(); // call this method multiple times if you want to execute tasks in parallel.
```